Stove plug wiring
This guy was installing a stove plug and the only wires inside were size 6 and 2 hots and a ground and he split the ground wires in half and put half on the neutral screw and half on the ground screw is that something you can do?

NO.  I would not have him back unless he pays a bond for your house, since your insurance will laugh in your face and keep your money(their right) if you have a fire.

Will need more info about the stove, a stove that uses two hots and a ground is safe.  A stove that uses two hots and neutral is not as safe(NEMA 10, banned in 96).  NEMA 10 stoves/dryers usually used a jumper between the neutral and ground at the stove/dryer, not at the plug and is highly recommended to use the modern NEMA 14 with two hots and separated ground and neutral if needed for your safety.

Do not use that circuit until repaired by a qualified electrician.
What you likely had is a legacy NEC 250.140(B)(4) installation that the bare wire of a type SE cable is designated a neutral.
This section allows grounding via neutral when the appliance has installation instructions on how to create this bond in the appliance (per NEC 110.3(B)). The NEC considers existing installations  of this 3 wire configuration to be safe enough to use if it was installed properly, but new installations are required to be 4-wire. Some electricians personally feel this option is so unsafe that they won't service this type of circuit.
What your "guy" did is create a further risk by reducing the size of a section of the equipment ground creating a choke or potential overheated ground or neutral that may not carry enough current in a fault situation to trip the breaker in a timely manner.
Your options are:
(1) Completely install a new 4-wire cable to make a modern safe installation. (Safest and most preferred option.)
(2) Route a new additional insulated ground wire to a connection point listed in NEC 250.130(C).
(3) Follow the instructions included with the appliance on how to install a 3 conductor cord to be used with a 3 wire receptacle. (Least safest and least preferred.)

You may get other answers or find other answers on this site which add a GFCI option, but I believe 250.114(3)(b) specifically requires specified appliances to be grounded (not just connected to a labelled and ungrounded ground-type receptacle.
